# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in lock_may_be_available()

Tags: database

I have about 5 drupal sites on in motion server but for some reason all sites are showing me the same error which is

"PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in lock_may_be_available()

My host is telling me that there is nothing out of the ordinary, but clearly some thing is wrong, all 5 websites are showing me this error simultaneously. I need a to resolve this issue , I need some help.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Notice that you simply stated facts, without asking any explicit question. Stack Exchange doesn't work well with implicit questions. Please add one that is not on the lines of "Any ideas?"